# What is in node_link_graph?

Tags: networkx

I don't see anything in `H`. Does anybody have an example that can demonstrate what node_link_graph does?

```
>>> from networkx.readwrite import json_graph
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> G = nx.Graph([('A', 'B')])
>>> data = json_graph.node_link_data(G)
>>> H = json_graph.node_link_graph(data)
>>> print(H)
```

Answer (score 0):

The method [`node_link_graph`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.json_graph.node_link_graph.html#networkx.readwrite.json_graph.node_link_graph) reconstruct the graph based on the given json data:

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.readwrite import json_graph
G = nx.Graph([('A', 'B')])
data1 = json_graph.node_link_data(G)

reconstructed_graph = json_graph.node_link_graph(data1)
print(G.edges)
# [('A', 'B')]
print(reconstructed_graph.edges)
# [('A', 'B')]
print(type(reconstructed_graph))
# <class 'networkx.classes.graph.Graph'>
```